# check if word start with uppercase or lowercase

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

i need to write a program that when it found `"."` in text it should check the next word if it starts with capital letter (uppercase) then it will but the word before "." in a list box if not (start with lowercase)then but the word before it in another list box 
i have this to far but its seems not useful  :

```
string st= File.ReadAllText(@"D:\\f1.txt");
textBox1.Text = st;
string[] s = st.Split(' ');
for (int i = 0; i <= s.Length; i++)
{
    if (s[i] == ".")
    {
        string v = s[i + 1];
        var c = v.ToCharArray();
        string ss=Convert.ToString(c[0]);
        if (Regex.IsMatch(ss, "[A-Z]"))
            listBox1.Items.Add(s[i - 1]);
        else
            listBox2.Items.Add(s[i - 1]);
    }
```

}

Comment: why don't you check if the value of `ss.StartsWith(ss.ToUpper())` or `ss.ToLower()` there is a `StartsWith` function in c# for Strings.. also you could use the `IndexOf` function to find the value after the `.` as well it would also help if you would edit the question and paste at least the first line of the text file so that we can see what it is you're seeing

Comment: Please explain what is the format of these strings. Does a space divide the point and the next/previous word? Is the point attached to the next word?

Comment: If you split at a space, you don't necessarily get the `.` in one array element of `s`. See e.g `Hello there. Nice weather`, if you split at the space you'll get `string[] s = { "Hello", "there.", "Nice", "weather" }`, so the check `s[i] == "."` won't be satisfied for any element in this collection for that case, your logic isn't quite right yet. It would be good to show us some lines of that `D:\f1.txt` file and expected outputs / findings.

Comment: thanks all for replays ^-^

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt 
 you are  right i'v check it , it does not split the point . as a single word  may i ask for your opinion what would you suggest instead of   ( string[] s = st.Split(' '); ) ???  ^-^

Comment: @MethodMan  i'm new to c# so i do not know all these functions , but i'll try to use what you suggest thanks  ;)

Comment: that's what the power of Google is there for new or not.. this is where a ton of examples exist

Comment: Splitting at the space is still okay, just make suure you don't check if the whole string `s[i]` is the `"."`, just check if it *contains* the string `"."` (there's a `Contains()` function..). Your other logic must then also a little bit rewritten, since you have a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` at the expression `string v = s[i+1]`, because if `i` is at the last index of the collection `s[i+1]` doesn't exist. The `for` loop is wrong, because in that current logic, it should iterate from `i=0` to `i < s.Length` (possibly to `i < s.Length-1` if you redo the logic further).

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt   thanks my friend i knew there was many things logically not right but couldnt specify it , thanks for advice you really helped ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [String.IndexOf(char, int)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/5xkyx09y(v=vs.110).aspx) to find the dot and then use [Char.IsUpper(char)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/9s91f3by(v=vs.110).aspx) to find out if it is uppercase or lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do it with a regex.

`(?<!\S)(\w+)\s+\.(?=\s+(\w+)(?!\S))`

Expanded

```
 (?<! \S )
 ( \w+ )                       # (1)
 \s+ 
 \.
 (?=
      \s+ 
      ( \w+ )                       # (2)
      (?! \S )
 )
```

In a while loop, on each match check if capture group 2 starts with a capital.
if so put capture 1 into list box 1, if not, put capture 1 in list box 2.

**Added**

Note that this is trying to emulate your code functionality.
Therefore it uses a lookahead for the second value, which in turn *can be*
the first value in the next value dot value pair.

C# sample

```
string f1_txt = @"abc . DEF . ghi . JKL some, junk, some, junk, mno . PQR some junk stu . VWX";
Regex Rx = new Regex(@"(?<!\S)(\w+)\s+\.(?=\s+(\w+)(?!\S))");

Match _matchData = Rx.Match( f1_txt );
while (_matchData.Success)
{
    if ( char.IsUpper(_matchData.Groups[ 2 ].Value[ 0 ] ) )
        Console.WriteLine("Add {0} to ListBox1", _matchData.Groups[ 1 ].Value);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Add {0} to ListBox2", _matchData.Groups[ 1 ].Value);
    _matchData = _matchData.NextMatch();
}
return;
```

Output

```
Add abc to ListBox1
Add DEF to ListBox2
Add ghi to ListBox1
Add mno to ListBox1
Add stu to ListBox1
```

Comment: :(   i'm totally new to c# and found Regex by the way i don't really know how to deal with it , would you mind to explain  further .

Answer (score 1):

Char.IsUpper() is obviously the simplest and most practical way.  However, if you wanted to impress an interviewer, this will work:

```
bool StartsWithUpper(string word)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(65, 26).Contains((int)word[0]);
}
```